# How to control a div, jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, so basically I can't get it to work with parent as the class isn't in the parent div.

CSS:

```
.contentSlide{
    display:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="contentSlide">
    <p>Members image on left and comments on the right. Date floated on right, and link to user.</p>
</div>

<div id="button" class="open">Comments(6) &#x25bc;</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".open").live('click',function(){
    $(this).parent(".contentSlide").slideDown();
    $(this).html("Close \u25b2 <span style='float:right;' onclick='reply=true;' class='reply'>Post a <a href='javascript:void(0);'>comment</a></span>").removeClass("open").addClass("close");
});
```

Basically, we want the div class "open" to make the "contentSlide" div slideDown if it is clicked.

We don't want to use `$(".contentSlide").slideDown();` as we want this to be global in the event that we have more than one of these contentSlide divs displaying on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of the HTML you've provided and that it's all we have to go by, you would want to use the [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) function.

```
$(this).prev().slideDown();
```

But I would suggest giving it an ID of some sort or a data type.